# $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x^x$ exists? and if so, what's its value?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

*Disclaimer: I am completely and utterly new here. Please openly correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.*

I received the following question on a recent calc test:
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty} x^x=?$$
$$a) 1 \quad b) \infty  \quad  c) 0   \quad  d) DNE$$

I selected $d) DNE$ as my answer as I believed the function $f(x) = x^x$ has a domain of $x \in (0, \infty)$, and any negative value will cause the function to oscillate between positive and negative values and result in discontinuities. I was sincerely surprised when the test was returned and the correct answer was $c) 0$.

My instructor's argument was that the function did not have to be continuous for the limit to exist, despite it being outside of the domain.

My argument was that for certain negative real numbers of the form $-\frac{2a+1}{2b}$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, the function will yield imaginary results of the form: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[2b]{\left(-\frac{2a+1}{2b}\right)^{2a+1}}}$$.
My friend also had a counter-example where $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ does not exist, but $\left(-\frac{2}{4}\right)^{-\frac{2}{4}}$ does.

I have done some research on my own, and I believe by the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, this limit does not exist as this limit does not satisfy that for all real $x$ in the needed range, $\left|f(x) - L\right| < \epsilon$.

Please lend help!

**Edit:** is there a (more) rigorous way to show that the limit does not exist?

Comment: For the reason you pointed out, negative numbers can only really be raised to integer powers. If your instructor meant the domain to be integers, then they're correct.

Comment: @ZoeAllen My instructor did not specify the domain of the function. The given problem, in its entirety, has been presented above.

Comment: @Seeker I don't think $\mathbb{Z}\cup\mathbb{R}^+$ is a reasonable domain. That's the backwards calculus "if the function can be made to work" definition of domain.

Comment: @obscurans I personally have no clue what a reasonable domain could be for this function. I’m a beginner in real analysis myself. I was just pointing out the key mistakes in the problem and argument.

Comment: @Seeker Well, you implied OP did something wrong in guessing a domain and working with it, when they still took a valid path to finding DNE (that the function fails to exist at arbitrarily large values of $-x$).

Comment: @obscurans I see what you mean. I misunderstood your previous comment. It is true that the OP couldn’t have made a really good educated guess given the information in the problem. I will delete my previous comment as it is useless.

Comment: @Seeker well, the part where the prof failed to define it, etc. was definitely spot-on (I upvoted it too)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Excellent first question

Comment: I also want to chime in that this is an excellent example of a first question. I agree with the assessment of others that, unless you're a math major or a 3rd year+ physics major, you almost certainly don't have the math background to get the limit to be zero. I'm not entirely sure *I* fully understand, because analysis isn't my strength. If this is a high school class, MSE is collectively face-palming at your teacher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you marked this as in calculus, not complex analysis, you're correct. For fractional negative $x$, you're definitely going to get complex results, and at the scope of calculus, those numbers don't exist, so clearly if the function doesn't even exist, what limit can?

If you're fully allowing complex numbers to show up, then you end up with a horrendous mess of intricate details such as branch cuts (choosing the complex argument), multivalued functions (or choose all!), and so on. The limit can (with much conceptual difficulty *and definitions you haven't learned*) be shown to be $0$ - see [@MarkViola's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4656678/619038).

Your instructor is doing the physics/engineering thing of saying because
$$x^y=\exp(y\ln(x))$$
*completely ignoring all the mathematical subtleties* (in particular, that $\ln(x)$ typically behaves the worst right at negative reals - it's the cut), then the limit can be "eventually" worked out.

When the initial steps already broke spectactularly.

---

For a rigorous argument that the limit fails to exist in real analysis:

1. $x^x$ fails to exist for all $\{-n-1/2\}, n\in\mathbb{N}$.
2. Therefore the function is undefined for arbitrarily large negative $x$.
3. Therefore the function cannot have any limit at all.
4. Suppose it did, and look at the definition for a limit at $-\infty$:
   $$\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}\quad|\quad x<\delta\Rightarrow\left|f(x)-L\right|<\epsilon$$
   but you can always exhibit a value $x<\delta$ where $f(x)$ is *undefined*, let alone within $\epsilon$ of any purported limit. $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

Comment: In the complex analysis interpretation, is it even a mess or is it just ill defined? there isn't a way to raise a negative number to an irrational power is there?

Comment: You have to do some form of functional continuation of the exponentiation function to allow for fully complex base and argument, and it's technically possible, with a bunch of cases that won't work.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) details some possibilities. The interesting thing? The price is that you break specifically these identities such as $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ no matter what you do.

Comment: The argument of $x$, $\arg(x)$, does not impact the magnitude of $x^x$, $\left|x^x\right|=\left|e^{x\log(|x|)+ix\arg(x)}\right|=e^{x\log(|x|)}$ for real values of $x$.  Therefore, irrespective of the definition of the complex logarithm, the coveted limit is indeed $0$.  I posted a solution accordingly.

Comment: @MarkViola I agree you have the answer correctly. My claim stands that *to a calculus student*, there remains at least a year of instruction before they can deal with the complex logarithm and its details (multiple definitions!) enough to be able to understand that kind of proof.

Comment: Well, I don't believe "at least a year of instruction" is necessary.

Comment: @MarkViola It's equally unrealistic to say "drop everything you're studying, just suddenly dive headlong into this specific line of complex analysis just so that you get to solve this ill-posed and not particularly relevant question". In a standard undergraduate curriculum, they have the rest of differential and integral calculus, multivariate calculus, set theory, real analysis, etc. as higher priority topics until they deal with complex analysis.

Comment: @obscurans And I've made no such assertion.  Note all of the qualifications I have made in the answer.   Now let's move on as it is late here and I grow weary of this conversation.  The OP asked "Is there a more rigorous way to show that the limit does not exist?" I've given a rigorous way to show that the limit does exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144524/discussion-between-obscurans-and-mark-viola).

Comment: In the definition of limit you forgot to require $x$ to belong to the domain. This limit does exist and is $0$ in the context of real analysis because $-\infty$ is a limit point of the domain and indeed for small enough $x$ in the domain you have $x^x$ arbitrarly small.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your class has covered the complex logarithm, which is multi-valued on $\mathbb{C}$, your answer is correct (i.e., in the context of real analysis, the limit does not exist).

However, in the context of complex analysis we have for $x\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\begin{align}
\left|x^x\right|&=\left|e^{x\log(|x|)+ix\arg(x)}\right|\\\\
&=e^{x\log(|x|)}
\end{align}$$

which does go to zero as $x\to -\infty$.  Therefore, irrespective of the choice of the definition of $\arg(x)$, the coveted limit is indeed $0$.

**NOTE**:  Note that here, $\arg(x)$ denotes the multi-valued argument.

Comment: We note that $x^x$ is multi-valued when $x<0$ and $x \not\in \mathbb Z$.  However, all the values have the same modulus.  That is, $|x^x|$ is the same for all values of $x^x$.  And (calculation) $\lim_{x\to-\infty} |x^x| = 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed.  I thought that was clear in the solution herein.